# Python:Can df['a']str.contains() have multiple condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 types of value in my df column A example shown below

```
123
123/123/123/123/123
123,,123,,123
1234-1234-1234
```

i want index of those value which do not have any type of sepertor in it

I tried like this but failed to get results

```
mask = df["A"].str.contains(',','/' na=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible invert logic - get all rows if only numbers without any separator use `^\d+$` - `^` means start of string, `\d+` means one or more digits and `$` means end of string - together only numbers values:

```
mask = df["A"].str.contains('^\d+$', na=False)

print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @jezrael can you explain the regular expression you have wriiten ^\d+$

Comment: @Raju - Edited answer.